# How to pass already declared variables into functions in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, variables, parameters

I am very new to Swift (experience in Java). I am rather confused at how one passes a variable into a function when the variable and value has already been declared.

```
func multiply(integer1: Int, integer2: Int) -> Int {
    let returnValue = integer1 * integer2
    return returnValue
}

var intX: Int = 5
var intY: Int = 10

print(multiply(intX, intY)) <- ?????????
```

why can we not pass variables by their previously declared name as you would in Java, C etc? Please allow for my noobishness as I am still learning. Any help is appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: You might want to read [Defining and Calling Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID159)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a method like `func multiply(integer1: Int, integer2: Int)` you have to call it like:

```
multiply(integer1: intX, integer2: intY)
```

In `Swift`, a function's parameters are usually **named parameters**. When calling the function you have to provide the parameters with the names too.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually call it like that, by declaring your function like:

```
func multiply(_ integer1: Int, _ integer2: Int) -> Int {
    let returnValue = integer1 * integer2
    return returnValue 
}
```

Note the _ , allowing you to ignore the argument label. For more, read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).